# Unresolved externals in C++ when using vectors and find

Tags: c++, find, stdvector, unresolved-external

I have tried this code in a totally separate project, and it works fine (the only difference being that the project that is not working is being exported as a DLL). Here is the code:

**RTATMATHLIB.CPP**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "RTATMATHLIB.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

double someFunc(double** Y, int length)
{
    vector<double> myVector;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        double value = (*Y)[i];

        vector<double>::iterator it = find(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), value);

        if(it != myVector.end())
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            myVector.push_back(value);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**RTATMATHLIB.H**

```
__declspec(dllexport) double someFunc(double** Y, int length);
```

**ERRORS**

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_Vector_const_iterator<double,class std::allocator<double> >::_Vector_const_iterator<double,class std::allocator<double> >(double *,class std::_Container_base_secure const *)" (??0?$_Vector_const_iterator@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@QAE@PANPBV_Container_base_secure@1@@Z)  RTATMATHLIB.obj RTATMATHLIB
Error   2   fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

And that's it. I am not sure why it works in the other project and not this one...

Comment: I'm guessing there is a debug runtime problem. What are your project settings? Any warnings?

Comment: @Bart: I am fairly new to C++ and so I am not sure which settings you mean? I apologize in advance for my ignorance. But there are no warnings.

Comment: make sure at the top that the little dropdown list says "Release" not "Debug". Also if you're just making C++ programs, when you create a New Project make sure you select the bubble that says "Empty Project" in the options (I see stdafx.h in your headers list, which is usually used in Windows applications).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found another forum post, where somebody seems to have reported the same exact problem that you are having. Please check to see if you have

```
_DEBUG
```

defined either in your project settings (under C/C++ -- Preprocessor) or somewhere in your code (or include files).

It looks as if std::vector thinks you are building a debug build, when you are in fact creating a release build.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 28):

The problem in my case was a Debug configuration with `Runtime Library` set to `Multi-threaded DLL`. The fix was to change it to `Multi-threaded Debug DLL`. The error is gone. Removing `_DEBUG` macro was also a kind of workaround, by I guess it's not a good idea because you end up with debug build linked to non-debug standard library.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I was getting: "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CrtDbgReportW". It had to do with my switch from 32 bit to 64 bit in my Direct3D11 application. In Visual Studio 2013 Community, this setting is found under Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library.

Comment: Me too, I was compiling breakpad with msvc2015 and needed /MD and it worked for release but needed /MDd for debug

Answer (score 3):

The problem was I had _DEBUG defined in C/C++->Preprocessor. Changing it to NDEBUG solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks you so much, so many issues with trying to get this to work its unbelievable...

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me with :
The problem in my case was a Debug configuration with Runtime Library set to Multi-threaded DLL. The fix was to change it to Multi-threaded Debug DLL