# Visual Studio error "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol"

Tags: visual-c++

I get this error in my program. I don't know what that means. can you help me ?

> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   **imp**_CrtDbgReportW     referenced in function "public: class std::_Vector_const_iterator > > & __thiscall
>   std::_Vector_const_iterator > >::operator+=(int)"
>   (??Y?$_Vector_const_iterator@V?$_Vector_val@U?$_Simple_types@PAVCommissionEmployee@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z)   C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\Base-Commission Employee\Base-Commission
>   Employee\main.obj

Comment: Your title is very general. Please edit it.

Comment: it can be the solution for your problem here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6004441/896258

Comment: This exact question was answered here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e126c79-77f3-4d50-a47f-a9ce35cff0a4/unresolved-external-symbol-impcrtdbgreportw

Answer (score 10):

Take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5fcad5be-f597-40fa-8912-9bb3d8ade853/linker-error-with-vector-use-multithreaded-dll-config) please:

> The vector class is going to want to tell you that the at() method
>   failed in debug mode.  Thus the reference to CrtDbgReportW(), the
>   runtime function that displays diagnostics while debugging.  When you
>   link with /MD, you link with the release version of the run-time
>   library; the one that doesn't tell you anything and is missing the
>   CrtDbgReportW() export.  Thus the linker error.
>
> **You can fix this by removing the _DEBUG define from the preprocessor
>   definitions.**  If you don't want to lose that valuable tool, tell us
>   what goes wrong when you link with /MDd.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a debug version with a static CRT linking (/MT) then just do this:
`#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0`  before`#include<vector> or #include<algorithm> and so on...`

Comment: This fixed it. Wrapped it as such:
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0
#include <crtdbg.h>
#endif